# how to freeze starting 3 or 4 column with header in a table and rest to be scrollable

Tags: html, css

I need the below-provided table, having the Starting first four columns to be freeze along with the header and having rest as scrollable.

For example:
Header 1, 2, 3, 4 And Column 1, 2, 3, 4 should be fixed and rest header and columns for example Header 5,6,7,8,9,10 and column 5,6,7,8,9,10 should be scrollable.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Hearder A</th>
                    <th>Hearder B</th>
                    <th>Hearder C</th>
                    <th>Hearder D</th>
                    <th>Hearder E</th>
                    <th>Hearder F</th>
                    <th>Hearder G</th>
                    <th>Hearder H</th>
                    <th>Hearder I</th>
                    <th>Hearder J</th>
                    <th>Hearder K</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>col 1 - C</td>
                    <td>col 2 - C</td>
                    <td>col 3 - C</td>
                    <td>col 4 - C</td>
                    <td>col 5 - C</td>
                    <td>col 6 - C</td>
                    <td>col 7 - C</td>
                    <td>col 8 - C</td>
                    <td>col 9 - C</td>
                    <td>col 10 - C</td>
                    <td>col 11 - C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>col 1 - C</td>
                    <td>col 2 - C</td>
                    <td>col 3 - C</td>
                    <td>col 4 - C</td>
                    <td>col 5 - C</td>
                    <td>col 6 - C</td>
                    <td>col 7 - C</td>
                    <td>col 8 - C</td>
                    <td>col 9 - C</td>
                    <td>col 10 - C</td>
                    <td>col 11 - C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>col 1 - C</td>
                    <td>col 2 - C</td>
                    <td>col 3 - C</td>
                    <td>col 4 - C</td>
                    <td>col 5 - C</td>
                    <td>col 6 - C</td>
                    <td>col 7 - C</td>
                    <td>col 8 - C</td>
                    <td>col 9 - C</td>
                    <td>col 10 - C</td>
                    <td>col 11 - C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>col 1 - C</td>
                    <td>col 2 - C</td>
                    <td>col 3 - C</td>
                    <td>col 4 - C</td>
                    <td>col 5 - C</td>
                    <td>col 6 - C</td>
                    <td>col 7 - C</td>
                    <td>col 8 - C</td>
                    <td>col 9 - C</td>
                    <td>col 10 - C</td>
                    <td>col 11 - C</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>col 1 - C</td>
                    <td>col 2 - C</td>
                    <td>col 3 - C</td>
                    <td>col 4 - C</td>
                    <td>col 5 - C</td>
                    <td>col 6 - C</td>
                    <td>col 7 - C</td>
                    <td>col 8 - C</td>
                    <td>col 9 - C</td>
                    <td>col 10 - C</td>
                    <td>col 11 - C</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed; 
    width: 100%;
    *margin-left: -100px;/*ie7*/
    text-align:left;
}

.outer {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

.inner {
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:visible;
    width:80%; 
    margin-left:50px;
}

td, th {
    vertical-align: top;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding:10px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

```css
        table {
            width: 100%;
        }

        thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

        tr:after {
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            visibility: hidden;
            clear: both;
        }

        thead th {
            height: 30px;

            /*text-align: left;*/
        }

        tbody {
            height: 120px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        thead {
            /* fallback */
        }


        tbody td, thead th {
            width: 19.2%;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

Comment: Nope. It's not working. Not providing the required result.

Comment: I have corrected the code. Run the code snippet. And, use bootstrap along with this. i have edited the code.